# MySQL: Creating buckets on the fly

Tags: mysql, graph, charts

I have a mysql table that stores network utilization for every five minutes, I want to now use this data for graphing. Is there a way where I could just specify the start time and the end time and the number of buckets / samples I need, and MySQL could in someway oblige :?

My table

```
+---------------------+-----+
| Tstamp              | QID |
+---------------------+-----+
| 2010-12-10 15:05:39 |  20 |
| 2010-12-10 15:06:09 |  26 |
| 2010-12-10 15:06:14 |  27 |
| 2010-12-10 15:06:18 |  28 |
| 2010-12-10 15:06:23 |  40 |
| 2010-12-10 15:10:38 |  20 |
| 2010-12-10 15:11:12 |  26 |
| 2010-12-10 15:11:17 |  27 |
| 2010-12-10 15:11:21 |  28 | 
------ SNIP ------
```

So can I specify I need 20 samples from the last 24 hours.

Thanks!

Harsh

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your DATETIME to a UNIX_TIMESTAMP, and play with division and modulo...

Comment: (only need division and TRUNC not modulo)

Comment: can you suggest an apt query for this?

Comment: Well, it's TRUNC( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP( tstamp ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( start_time )) / 300 ) or something...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample query you can use. Notice it does not work if the number of requested samples in the given time range is more than half of the available records for that range (which would mean the bucket size is one).

```
-- Configuration
SET @samples = 4;
SET @start = '2011-05-06 19:44:00';
SET @end =   '2011-05-06 20:46:50';
--

SET @bucket = (SELECT FLOOR(count(*)/@samples) as bucket_size FROM table1
WHERE Tstamp BETWEEN @start AND @end);

SELECT
      SUM(t.QID), FLOOR((t.ID-1)/@bucket) as bucket
FROM (SELECT QID , @r:=@r+1 as ID
     FROM table1
     JOIN (SELECT @r:=0) r
     WHERE Tstamp BETWEEN @start AND @end
     ORDER BY Tstamp) as t
GROUP BY bucket
HAVING count(t.QID) = @bucket
ORDER BY bucket;
```

P.S. I believe there is a more elegant way to do this, but since no one has provided a working query I hope this helps.